# Counting Sefira without a beracha during the day twice in a row?

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer

If someone forgot to count Sefirat HaOmer at night and therefore counted during the following day without a beracha (as per the halacha OC 489), and then forgot to count Sefirat HaOmer again the following night (and so counts without a beracha again the following day) may they resume counting with a beracha on the third night? Is there some maximum number of consecutive nights which may בדיעבד be missed after which one may no longer make a beracha?

Comment: The safek isn't bigger just because there are two instances of it  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71788/759

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the answers to [Is there an obligation to Count the Omer without a Bracha?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71781/is-there-an-obligation-to-count-the-omer-without-a-bracha) we see that

> The Terumat HaDeshen (#37) writes that if you aren't sure if you
>   missed a day, then you don't need to worry about the opinion of the
>   Behag, since it's only a doubt about a minority opinion and we don't
>   need to be that worried about Berakha Levatalla. This is the ruling of
>   the Shulchan Arukh (OC 589:8). Counting one day during the daytime (or
>   any other doubtful counting) is no worse than being unsure if one
>   counted at all (Levush, etc., ibid.) and one should proceed to further
>   days as if they are for sure obligated to count.

Since each time one has that problem, it is no worse a situation (because one has recovered correctly), the one should count the remainder with a bracha